# Android ListView search only change target value in the row, all other data on row do not change

Tags: android, listview, search, filtering, android-filterable

I am trying since last some days but I didn't achieve my goal. The problem I am facing in my code is when I type in EditText for search in list view as the searching criteria depend on 'Policy No'. It works perfect for single value (Policy No) and it changes as I type. But the remaining other values doesn't changes it remains on their own places. Kindly Help me for this. Thanks In Advance . and sorry for my bad English.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Interpolator.Result;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ListViewAdapter_claimlist extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

Activity context;
String claimid[];
String ref[];
String policy[];
String natureofloss[];
String status[];

private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

 private List<String>originalData = null;
 private List<String>filteredData = null;

 private List<String>claimidFilter = null;
 private List<String>refFilter = null;
 private List<String>nautreoflossfilter = null;
 private List<String>statusFilter = null;

 ArrayList<abc> alldata = new ArrayList<abc>();


public ListViewAdapter_claimlist(Activity context, String[] claimid, String[] ref,String[] policy, String[] natureofloss, String[] status) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.claimid = claimid;
    this.ref = ref;
    this.policy = policy;
    this.natureofloss = natureofloss;
    this.status = status;

    this.filteredData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.policy));
    this.originalData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.policy));

    this.claimidFilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.claimid));
    this.refFilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.ref));
    this.nautreoflossfilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.natureofloss));
    this.statusFilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.status));

    for(int i = 0; i<this.claimid.length; i++)
    {
        abc a = new abc();
        a.setClaimid(claimid[i]);
        a.setRef(ref[i]);
        a.setPolicy(policy[i]);
        a.setNatureofLoss(natureofloss[i]);
        a.setStatus(status[i]);
        alldata.add(a);
    }

}

public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView cliamid;
    TextView ref;
    TextView policy;
    TextView natureofloss;
    TextView status;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowitem_cliamlist, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.cliamid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_claims);
        holder.ref = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_referencepolicy);
        holder.policy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_policyNo);
        holder.natureofloss = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_natureoflos);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_claimstatus);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    Button b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_quotaions_claims);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), QuotationList.class); 
            intent.putExtra("quot_id", holder.cliamid.getText().toString());
            Constants.claim_id = holder.cliamid.getText().toString();
            context.startActivity(intent);  
        }
    });

    Button c = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_claimdetail_claims);
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(holder.ref.getText().toString(), "/");
            String first = tokens.nextToken();
            String two = tokens.nextToken();
             Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), Claimform.class); 
                intent.putExtra("ref_id", first);
                intent.putExtra("typeofintimation", holder.natureofloss.getText().toString());
                Constants.key_id = first;
                context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    abc aa = alldata.get(position);
    holder.cliamid.setText(aa.getClaimid());
    holder.ref.setText(aa.getRef());
    holder.policy.setText(filteredData.get(position));
    holder.natureofloss.setText(aa.getNatureofloss());
    holder.status.setText(aa.getStatus());

return convertView;

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     public Filter getFilter() {
            return mFilter;
        }

        private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                final List<String> list = originalData;

                int count = list.size();
                final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

                String filterableString ;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    filterableString = list.get(i);

                    if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                        nlist.add(filterableString);


                    }
                }

                results.values = nlist;
                results.count = nlist.size();


                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        public class abc
        {
            String claimid;
            String ref;
            String policy;
            String natureofloss;
            String status;

             public void setClaimid(String claimid)
             { 
                 this.claimid = claimid;
             }
             public void setRef(String ref)
             {
                 this.ref = ref;
             }
             public void setPolicy(String policy)
             {
                 this.policy = policy;
             }
             public void setNatureofLoss(String natureofloss)
             {
                 this.natureofloss = natureofloss;
             }
             public void setStatus(String status)
             {
                 this.status = status; 
             }

             public String getClaimid()
             {
                 String claimid = this.claimid;
                 return claimid;
             }
             public String getRef()
             {

                 String ref = this.ref;
                 return ref;
             }
             public String getPolicy()
             {

                 String Policy = this.policy;
                 return Policy;
             }
             public String getNatureofloss()
             {

                 String Natureofloss = this.natureofloss;
                 return Natureofloss;
             }
             public String getStatus()
             {

                 String Status = this.status;
                 return Status;
             }

        }
```

}

EditText Event

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int  count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ClaimList.this.lviewAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

***Use these following lines of code...It can be helpful for you***

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int  count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ClaimList.this.lviewAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchText.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: thank for reply....i tried it but doesn't work... by the way it successfully sends Characters to that class... the problem is in here                                            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values; some where

Comment: and the policy no changes because it gets the position and text like....  
    holder.policy.setText(filteredData.get(position));  where else other TextViews get text from class and that's my own logic

Comment: What problem are you getting??..Are you not filter data or any other problem..Tell me ,i will try it

Comment: filtering is working but only on one value on Policy No..... As in single Row of listview there are multiple Textviews so the other textviews text doesn't changes with policy no as i expect.

Comment: Means you try to say that...when u enter the only digit on Policy number than it filter the data easily but it becomes fail to search the data when the number of character on Policy number more than 1...Am i right??

Comment: no dear...i am saying that It works perfectly search out Policy number but the can't be search with Policy Number because each row has different Policy Number, Status, Nature of loss etc. Those values stay on their place but policy number changes by searching.... if you want to see my code kindly join me on skype ... id= sahir.khan1991

Comment: Sorry bro...I am in the office..there is no allow to do these without there permission...

Comment: its ok dudeanother time